# What should we consider as the final output of the Apriori Algorithm

Tags: data-mining, apriori

I am using Apriori Algorithm to find frequent item sets.There I use minimum support as 2 and I got the output as follows, the item sets which has 2 or more support;

[3,5] [1,3] [2,5] [2,3] [2,3,5]

All the above item sets have a support value more than min support.
But I am confuse which item set should I consider as frequent item set among these 5 item sets, Also I want to know usually what we get as the final output of the Apriori Algorithm,Is it only one final set or more than one set regardless of the **size** of the set?

Thanks

Comment: do you mean "which itemset should you consider as `THE MOST` frequent among" them?

Comment: yes. which Item set should I use to recommend items for the user at the end?

Comment: Did you have a look at R's `arules` package. Rules coming from `apriori()` function could be sorted by `confidence`. If I were to use "Apriori" as a recommender, I would chose rules with similar `lhs` and out of them pick up `rhs` that would have highest `confidence`. You may read about R's realization of `apriori` algo [here](http://rpubs.com/sbushmanov/180410)

Comment: Thanks. I think this is helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Your result is incomplete. It is missing all the frequent 1-itemsets.

Also, you should keep the frequencies.

You always need the frequent itemsets, but often you will want to derive **association rules** from them.